# Generating a macro button with a macro

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2013, I am looking to insert code into preexisting macro called "Rebuild_TOC" to generate a macro button on my "TOC" worksheet which calls "Repair_Back_To_TOC", a macro. I would like it to appear on my TOC at cells C2:E3, if possible, named "Rebuild Back to TOC Hyperlinks".

How would I go about accomplishing this with my current code?:

```
Sub Rebuild_TOC()

Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnPages As Long
Dim lnCount As Long

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

' If the TOC sheet already exist delete it and add a new worksheet.
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
With wbBook
    .Worksheets("TOC").Delete
    .Worksheets.Add Before:=.Worksheets(1)
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo 0

Set wsActive = wbBook.ActiveSheet
With wsActive
    .Name = "TOC"
    With.Range("A1:B1")
        .Value = Array("Table of Contents", "Sheet # – # of Pages")
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End With

lnRow = 2
lnCount = 1

' Iterate through the worksheets in the workbook and create sheetnames, add hyperlink
' and count & write the running number of pages to be printed for each sheet on the TOC.
For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    If wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name Then
        wsSheet.Activate
        With wsActive
            .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(lnRow, 1), "", _
            SubAddress:= wsSheet.Name & "!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=wsSheet.Name
            lnPages = wsSheet.PageSetup.Pages().Count
            .Cells(lnRow, 2).Value = "‘" & lnCount & "-" & lnPages
        End With
        lnRow = lnRow + 1
        lnCount = lnCount + 1
    End If
Next wsSheet

wsActive.Activate
wsActive.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do your hyperlinks actually work?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I just realized they are not working; I'm getting the error: "Reference is not valid". I had this part working about half a week ago, not sure what has gone wrong at this point.

Comment: I am working on fixing the code that generates those links now.

Comment: Possibly `SubAddress:= wsSheet.Name & "!A1", _`

Comment: @Davesexcel Bingo! Thank you very much for pointing that out, I found one of the issues and used your recommendation to clear up the rest. I must have been leaning on the keyboard. :P

Comment: I'd also like to state that I no longer have a need for this question, I found an alternative solution. I am now using a button in the quick access ribbon to run one of my macros.